# Proving something is a linearly independent subset

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the set of vectors
$$\left\{sin(x), sin(2x),sin(2^2x),\dots,sin(2^nx)\right\}$$

form a linearly independent subset of $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

I know that to form a linearly independent subset the set must be closed under addition, closed under scalar multiplication, and contain the neutral element. 
Showing that it contains the neutral element is relativley straight forward since when $x=0$ every element also equals $0$. Therefore this subset contains the neutral element. However, I am having a hard time coming up with a way to approach the parts showing that it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition for all $x$. Do you have a piece of advice or a hint on how to approach those part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

To show linearly independent, you are supposed to show that if $\forall x,$

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\sin(2^ix) = 0$$

implies that $a_i = 0$.

To do so, you might like to choose special value of $x$.

Closed under addition and scalar multiplication are conditions for a subspace.

Comment: I have been trying to work through this using $x = \frac{\pi}{2^k}$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. I am able to conclude that some of the values will be zero if $k\leq i$ else $0<sin(2^{i-k}\pi)\leq 1$ but how would we be able to use this to imply that $a_i = 0$?

Comment: hmmm... let's try another approach. prove that $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(px)\sin(qx) = 0 \, dx$ if $p \neq q$.